# Why does my EVO Android phone screen keep turning on?

Tags: battery-life, screen, htc-evo

I have an HTC EVO and I can be sitting around doing nothing, when all of a sudden the screen comes on and stays on. I try to turn it off, but it keeps turning back on - sometimes after a second, sometimes after a few minutes. If I just leave it, it will not turn off by itself, as it would if I manually turned it on but didn't enter the password. This is killing my already horrendous battery life!

I have killed almost all background processes except some of the ones by HTC that looked important.

I have also turned off application refresh, wifi, blue tooth, tried rebooting ... even put it into Airplane mode. Arghhh! Nothing helps!

I thought I hit pay dirt last week - I replaced the factory 1500mAh battery with a 3500mAh for obvious reasons. For a few days the auto-turn-on seemed to be cured but now it has started happening again.

Any ideas how I can get this paper weight to be more obedient?

Thanks, Victor

Answer (score 1):

First, killing background processes will do nothing; they'll just be restarted.  Instead, focus on apps.  You could use an app like Titanium Backup (requiees root) to "freeze" an app, and see if the problem stops.  If it does you know what app is the problem.  Then uninstall it, or turn off background sync for it or something if that might be the problem.  TB can uninstall system apps, but be careful which ones.

I had this problem when I had SipDroid installed -- every time its connection dropped and came back up, it would turn on the screen.